# Como trabajar en desarrollo con Symfony 4.x.x

Tags: php, symfony3, symfony4, yml

Antes con Symfony (2.8 a 3.4) usaba app_dev.php para trabajar en desarrollo. Si necesitaba trabajar en desarrollo configuraba en este fichero una lista blanca de ips permitida para poder entrar. A partir de ahora en la versión **4.x** eliminaron este php y dejaron solo index.php usando **.env** para configurar variables de entorno en dev y prod.

En la instalación por defecto el modo dev esta activo. Pero necesito que no muestre a los usuarios la barra de desarrollo porque siempre aparece activa.

Este es el fichero **.env** elimine las lineas innecesarias para el ejemplo:

```
APP_ENV=dev

TRUSTED_PROXIES=127.0.0.1
#TRUSTED_HOSTS='^localhost|example\.com$'

MAILER_URL=null://localhost
```

Existe alguna forma de acceder al entorno de `DEV` en producción (Se que no es lo recomendable) de alguna forma similar a la de antes?

Se agradecería poder acceder al modo `DEV` de esta forma por un puerto como se refleja en la imagen de abajo.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Es muy sencillo,
simplemente:

```
# config/packages/dev/web_profiler.yaml

web_profiler:
    toolbar: false
    intercept_redirects: false
```

Espero que te solucione.